# Passing PHP variables to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

There are a number of tutorials about passing PHP variables in Javascript ([for example](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/2760/best-practice-for-getting-php-variables-into-javascript/p1#Comment_19620)). There are 3 alternative methods I am aware of:

1. Using AJAX: A separate Javascript file is used to load the required data, then loaded into all HTML (or PHP) pages where required
2. Hidden form inputs: e.g. `<input type="hidden" id="X" value="<?php echo $X;?>"/>` and then using Javascript to get the value
3. Injecting Javascript into the returned HTML: e.g. `<script> var X = "<?php echo $X;?>";</script>`

But I am concerned that these methods are not really secure (**EDIT:** what I need is to just hide variables from the source code , more is not possible), and can become confusing when the number of variables to pass is large.

Are there any tips or tricks to pass large numbers of variables , from PHP to Javascript? What methods do major websites (Wikipedia, Google, etc.) use?

**EDIT2:** for example
imagine I'm going to pass rootpath of my project and some form keys to js
I'm passing rootpath in this case so I can't link everything before it(I can't use external JS)
and it's really *Unbecoming* to have something like this:

```
<script>
     rootpath = "example/foo";
     KEY1 = "example";
     KEY2 = "example";
</script>
```

and also this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="rootpath" value="example/foo"/>
<input type="hidden" id="KEY1" value="example"/>
<input type="hidden" id="KEY2" value="example"/>
```

think about a bigger project with lot's of variables to be passed

Comment: How do you mean they are not "secured"? What security do you expect from JavaScript - it's executed on the client's machine. It can be edited by client. All data JavaScript is working with can be seen by page visitor.

Comment: my fault! I've meant the showing of the code , at last there is no trusted way to secure a variable in JS , but I'm looking for a way to hide it from source code

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be perfectly secure if used with some common sense and a couple of checks here and there, but hiding a variable looks like impractical (or maybe overkill) to me.

However, that doesn't mean you can't approach your goal while specifying your variables. Maybe you could try something like `mcrypt_encrypt()` to define your variable as an encrypted value and using `mcrypt_decrypt()` in the server side to get the value you try to hide.

Don't take me wrong... it's as overkill as hiding or obfuscating the code is, plus you have to store the initialization vector and the key somewhere to be able to decrypt the value on its way back.

So it's more like a mixture between step C and A. Encrypt your variables, send them to PHP through AJAX and decrypt them afterwards.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<?php
  $php_var="Hello World";
?>   

<script>

   var js_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
   alert(js_var);
</script>
```